SpringToolSuite 4.25: enable autocomplete for Spring Files
I'm migrating my workspace and development environment from

Spring Tool Suite 3.7.3

to

Spring Tool Suite 4 Version: 4.25.0.RELEASE

In the old version, it's very helpful, when editing an Spring XML beans file, to press Ctrl+Space and, STS autocomplete the class name, or STS shows all the properties/attributes of the bean.
In the new version, it doesn't work for me. How can I configure or activate this?
I have read about "Content Assist" configuration. When I'm editing a Java source file, Ctrl+Space works. So my question is about an Spring beans file in XML.
Thank you.

Are you aware that Spring Tools 4 works quite differently than STS3? What do you mean by "I'm migrating my workspace"? Which tutorials/documentation/videos did you follow?

@howlger, some components require JDK21, and STS 4 works better and is newer. I haven't followed any tutorial. I have created a maven component for Spring6, I have added a Spring Beans XML, and Ctrl+Space didn't work. Thank you.

The support for Spring XML config files in the Spring Tools 4 is not enabled by default. You need to enable this in the preferences via Preferences -> Spring -> XML Config Files -> Enable Spring XML Config files support.
Once that is active, you will get the mentioned features showing up in Spring XML config files.
In case you are missing a specific feature, please raise an enhancement request at https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/issues.

that works perfectly. Thanks a lot!
